# Function is not producing an integer, but instead producing a "none" output

Tags: python

The getvalidint function is explained below, as I am calling the function getvalidint and giving it a input so it may produce an integer output. It is not as I print the functions output(see below in the main program) it prints out "none", I am running on python33.

```
#getValidInt() takes in a minn and maxx, and gets a number from the
#               user between those two numbers (inclusive)
#Input:      minn and maxx, two integers
#Output:     an integer, between minn and maxx inclusive


MIN_VAL = -1000000
MAX_VAL =  1000000

def getValidInt(minn, maxx):
    message = "Please enter a number between " + str(minn) + " and " + \
        str(maxx) + " (inclusive): "
    newInt = int(input(message))
    while newInt <= minn & newInt >= maxx:

    # while loop exited, return the user's choice
        return newInt

def main():

    userNum = getValidInt(MIN_VAL, MAX_VAL)
    print(userNum)

main()
```

Comment: Indentation is important. Your return statement is on a different indentation level than the function. It looks like it's part of the loop. If the loop is never hit, you don't return anything...

Answer (score 2):

If the `while newInt <= minn & newInt >= maxx:` condition is never met, then nothing will be returned. This means that the function will implicitly return `None`. Also, assuming you're using python 3 (which I induced from your `int(input())` idiom).

The deeper issue is that the input code will only run once, regardless of whether or not the value meets the constraint. The typical way of doing this would be something along the lines of:

```
import sys

def get_int(minimum=-100000, maximum=100000):
    user_input = float("inf")
    while user_input > maximum or user_input < minimum:
        try:
            user_input = int(input("Enter a number between {} and {}: ".format(minimum, maximum)))
        except ValueError:
            sys.stdout.write("Invalid number. ")
    return user_input
```

Comment: is there any way of doing it without import sys method??

Comment: Importing sys is only to use sys.stdout which is what print() uses by default. The only point was to make "Invalid number" appear on the same line as "Enter a number..." upon failure. This is purely for aesthetics. If you are using python3, an identical effect can be achieved with `print("Invalid Number", end="")`